# Magento 2 Slow import when 900 attribute options

Tags: magento2, php, database, importexport, slowbackend

We have a store with 35000 sku and there are 950 attribute options -

We find that when making any updates to products like price or qty or any other changes it is very very slow - like 5 mins if saving via Admin

We have tried some import/export extension like Firebear but these also seem to be slow

Came across this patch by Magento -
MDVA-31021: slow import and export

[link to patch page](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/support-tools/patches/mdva-31021-magento-patch-slow-import-and-export-if-many-product-options.html?lang=en)

1. Has anyone tried this and does it make any difference? with import speeds

With Native Magento Import or With other Import Extensions?

2. Has anyone tried it with Magento 2.4.3    Adobe Commerce (all deployment methods) 2.3.0 - 2.4.1

UPDATE

the requested database information can be downloaded from here
[download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10W92JsWoADw_a4-BK2dCI7hP5HCJBOKE/view?usp=sharing)

I had to export as csv files and put them according to the A B C etc host provided with the dump file as I was not allowed root access.

cloud server with 4GB RAM 2 Core 80GB SSD Hd

Apache
Elasticsearch
Memcached
MySQL MariaDB
Nginx
PHP FPM
Redis
Varnish

Comment: Check logs, I have recently imported 400k products with custom attributes data  and also categories,, it took me 20-30 minutes per 15-20k skus' data. magento2.4.4

Comment: @ Zahid thanks were you importing using native magento import or via any extension? and what should you be looking for in logs because we cant find anything clear which can be causing this. This only happened after we created 900 custom attributes went this slow

Comment: Yes native magento importer. please can you tell me how much custom attributes are you imporitng at the time? you should import like this : skus 30-40 custom attributes with 20-25k values than it will not take much time. so you must first create chunks of data and run it on daily basis.

Comment: actually we created 920 custom attributes some are magento own- we have not imported any of the sku with the custom attributes yet - products have already been imported with all the usual attributes fairly quickly - but after we created the additional 920 sku import has gone very very slow we tested with just import 1 attribute like manufacturer (magento attribute) taking like 30 hours- we have cleared and flushed and done reindex and importing via ssh

Comment: Yes this may be issue with your server or magento, you need to debug it, according to yoru last comment I also faced this same issue with 3 magento websites, may be it is magento bug. when we import lots of products like 700k (I imported in 3 magento 2.3 ) and after 700k every you new entry tokk time more than minutes. But you can try this solution: take 500 skues and import same file 3 times, 3rd time will import fastly. or if you share your admin I may try it on. it is not related with indexes.
Thanks

Comment: spent 3 days on this server side there are no errors tweaked few settings database - php etc but not making any difference. im thinking its the way magento in saving updates to products - seems to be checking for every single product attribute on each run - rather than only importing or updating any that need to be added or changed - even when trying to make any change in Admin to product is taking 5 mins to save changes

Comment: may be something wrong with magento application, regularly it imports everything on the sku of products. make it's clone on local machine and make some chnages in mysql query time out related and see what ia happening.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @nem3943 The previous user is requesting more information about the server hardware and MySQL results; so please provide that so they can assist more.   I may have an alternative, [Magmi for Magento 2](https://github.com/macopedia/magmi-m2).  *NOTE*: I use a modified version of this fork for our use, since that repo is not maintained anymore; however this is specific to our requirements.   That source fork is a good start; it actually imports 10k products in less than ~8 minutes (but we have 200+ attributes only); so not 100% the scale of your requirements.

Comment: For us personally it is much faster than the built-in importer, and we don't use built-in importer anymore.  The main problem you would have is to figure out which attributes are **required (ie. slightly custom)** for Magmi itself.  The other problem is you would need to be able to convert your **configurable products** into the format and input Magmi requires.  I imagine if you had a few test files with only a few test entries to see how it goes, and from there figure out how you would be able to convert your data into this template format; it would require some work and testing.

Comment: Also, as I am mentioning columns required are different, it would require you to convert all your data into bulk once Magmi works for you. This is an alternative option as you mentioned `With other Import Extensions`.

Comment: @CvRChameleon thank you - its cloud server with 4GB RAM 2 Core 80GB SSD Hd - I already reduced the attributes now to 150 custom attributes now save in admin is faster more like normal this is with reindex set to scheduled - but import is still very slow at the moment I am running import to add option values attributes I created still taking 6 hours to add these - using firebear import extension - starts fast then gets slower and slower

Comment: @ Wilson Hauck please can you check the updated post with the download link - i put them in separate  folders but could only export as csv files. would appreciate if you can provide any feedback

Comment: @nem3943 In my opinion 4GB RAM will be a bottleneck for Magento 2 to run reliably without issues (regardless of imports), it needs more RAM just for all other processes on server that runs in background. Going back to imports: if imports are still taking that long even with reduced (150) attributes, I want to recommend using that Magmi fork for Magento 2 even more.  The initial conversion of columns and data will be take time, but if setup correctly; importing and updating 3-4k products (weekly) will take you around 10-15 minutes (including reindexing).  Means converting saves time in future.

Comment: @CvRChameleon thanks which version magento are you using Magmi with we will need to run price and qty updates every 2 -3 days. On same server we imported actual products then without the addtional custom attributes we added now - it imported in 2 hours with images - but we noticed the slow import now after the addtional attriutes have been added -

Comment: @nem3943 Thanks for additional information posted.  Analysis in process.  Suggestions to be posted within next couple hours.  Agree with other observations, 4GB 2cores is very small today.  Doubling both, if affordable would be in your best interest.

Comment: @nem3943 Please have a look at some database configuration settings you can do to optimize from the answers below.  Regarding Magmi, we are running on Magento 2.3.7, and it works perfectly for us (as mentioned the initial setup of getting correct columns is the hardest part); I would say your 20k+ products should take less than 30 minutes with Magmi even on that hardware. (Our imports of 5k+ products per brand takes us around 5 minutes, plus 5 minutes for indexing).  I honestly do not know how people use the built-in Magento 2 importer with a large volume of products....

Comment: @ CvRChameleon thank you - we have never used the inbuilt import - always used third party and Firebear extension since last 7 years - can you please provide link to the magmi fork you are using

Comment: @nem3943 did you try to apply the changes as my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Magento official share some optimization for MariaDB (and MySQL), let's apply them:

1. For best efficiency, specify a combination of `innodb_buffer_pool_instances` and `innodb_buffer_pool_size` so that each buffer pool instance is at least 1 GB.
2. Reindexing on MariaDB 10.4 takes more time compared to other MariaDB or MySQL versions. As a workaround, we suggest modifying the default MariaDB configuration and setting the following parameters:

[optimizer_switch='rowid_filter=off'](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/optimizer-switch/)

[optimizer_use_condition_selectivity = 1](https://mariadb.com/products/skysql/docs/reference/es/system-variables/optimizer_use_condition_selectivity/)

Reference:

- https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/performance-best-practices/configuration.html
- https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/performance-best-practices/software.html

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section with present 4G 2 cores

```
max_connections=100  # from 600 since max_used_connections was 32 in 5 days
innodb_io_capacity=500  # from 200 to use more of your available SSD IOPS available
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve 90% of CPU cycles used for function every second
max_allowed_packet=512M  # from 1G until RAM is doubled
thread_pool_size=2  # from 128 autoconfig to throttle threads_running until more cores available
read_rnd_buffer_size=32K  # from 256K to redud handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 4,131
innodb_change_buffer_max_size=50  # from 25 (percent) to expedite row maintenance
```

View profile for contact info.  Many more opportunities exist to improve performance.

Comment: thanks we are working with host on this will contact you soon